# Magento Shipping Estimation Script Not Working

Tags: shipping, php-7, magento1.9.2.3, shipping-charges

PHP Shipping Estimation script (From StackExchange )

```
    <?php
//require_once("Mage.php");
ob_start();
require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors',true); 
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

// require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
// Mage::app('main');

//Mage::app();

function getShippingEstimate($productId,$productQty,$countryId,$postcode ) {

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
    $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);

    $quote->addProduct($_product, $productQty);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($countryId)->setPostcode($postcode); 
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

    $_rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

    $shippingRates = array();
    foreach ($_rates as $_rate):
            if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) {
                $shippingRates[] =  array("Title" => $_rate->getMethodTitle(), "Price" => $_rate->getPrice());
            }
    endforeach;

    return $shippingRates;

}
echo "<pre>";
//product id, quantity, country, postcode
print_r(getShippingEstimate('14419','1',"IN","642001"));
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Error :

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception in /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1377
Stack trace:
#0 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(861): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /home/abc/public_html/sp_cost.php(17): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore('default')
#2 /home/abc/public_html/sp_cost.php(43): getShippingEstimate('14419', '1', 'IN', '642001')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 1377
```

How to solve the error and get estimation shipping charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
//require_once("Mage.php"); 
    ob_start(); 
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php'); 
    umask(0); 
    ini_set('display_errors',true); 
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); 
    Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend'); 

    function getShippingEstimate($productId,$productQty,$countryId,$postcode ) { 

 // Change below line based on your store_view_code.
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('{store_view_code}')->getId()); ; 
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); 

    $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false); 
    $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false); 

    $quote->addProduct($_product, $productQty); 
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($countryId)->setPostcode($postcode); 
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals(); 
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true); 
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates(); 

    $_rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection(); 

    $shippingRates = array(); 
    foreach ($_rates as $_rate): 
    if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) { 
        $shippingRates[] = array("Title" => $_rate->getMethodTitle(), "Price" => $_rate->getPrice()); 
    } 
    endforeach; 

    return $shippingRates; 
    } 
    echo "<pre>"; 
    //product id, quantity, country, postcode 
    print_r(getShippingEstimate('13541','5',"IN","642001")); 
    echo "</pre>"; 
?>
```

> If you use **multiple store view** than change below line based on your store_view_code.
>
> $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore(**'{store_view_code}'**)->getId());

Comment: Code : https://paste.ofcode.org/pnHg7Eaup7WVdJLXNiqV5M   outut : https://snag.gy/t8J41H.jpg @Sweety Masmiya

Comment: I am using same code and I getting proper result. see the output :- https://prnt.sc/ncl4nv

Comment: In which location you are create your file ?

Comment: Actually this is my custom PHP page which is located in root folder. Path => public_html/code.php and my code execution like magento.com/code.php

Comment: Yes. I am also doing same.

Comment: check with my updated post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92498/discussion-between-zus-and-sweety-masmiya).